# Android Studio debugger crashes/stops on breakpoint, when debugging on my Huawei phone

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, crash, huawei-mobile-services

After the debugger reaches the breakpoint, the app process stops and after a little time (2-3 seconds) the debugger disconnect itself. But only if i debug with my Huawei phone (EMUI 10).

These are the last 3 lines from the log:

> D/: [ZeroHung]zrhung_send_event: wp = 257, ret = 0
>   D/:[ZeroHung]zrhung_send_event: wp = 258, ret = 0
>   Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8629', transport: 'socket'

If I debug the same app with the same breakpoint on an emulator, everything works fine. The debugger stops at the breakpoint, and doesn´t disconnect itself.

Comment: You should paste more logs. Can you check if your Huawei is missing anything from Google services like map?

Comment: Your app is crashed in your Huawei phone. Some of your code not working in your phone and same code is working in emulator. check your code.

Comment: I have the same problem. Before updating the version it worked perfectly.

Comment: I have this problem too, it started happening after update to Emui 10.

Comment: any updates on this problem?

Answer (score 0):

How did you build this project? If you build it with ant or other tools, make sure to compile with debugging information enabled (debug = true for ant javac tasks). Obfuscation and bytecode detection during construction can also affect the possibility of debugging. If you run it in some non-standard JVM, it can also cause such problems
When performing remote debugging, make sure to start the target process using the correct JVM options recommended in the IntelliJ idea remote debugging configuration. Your wrapper configuration may pass them incorrectly